# How to view the full commit diff in tig when viewing the diff for a single file?

Tags: git, tig

In the [Tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/) text-mode interface for git, one can view a blame for an individual file and then open a diff view to see that commit that modified that line. e.g.

```
tig blame file.cpp
(Select a line, press enter.)
```

However, the diff displayed is limited to the individual file, even if the commit modified multiple files. This is a good default, but is there a way to expand this view to full commit with diff across all files?

The current work around is to copy paste the commit hash, exit, and then use either git or tig  to show it.

Comment: I don't think it is currently possible. Tig is a great tool, but still clearly has lots of features missing yet. Maybe you can suggest it as [an issue](https://github.com/jonas/tig/issues).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the toggle-files action. By default it is bound to '%'.

Comment: Hey, that's cheating ;) You just implemented the feature a few hours ago.

Comment: What was I to do, I had a couple of free hours and I didn't want to let you down. :)

Comment: As of version 2.0, the file filter is togglable using the new `:toggle` prompt command, e.g. `:toggle file-filter`. `%` is still used as the default binding.